# Restore NuGet package from 3rd party source

Tags: .net, visual-studio, mono, nuget, travis-ci

I tried to use command-line `nuget` to restore NuGet package, like:

```
nuget restore BuptAssistant.sln
```

But I used some packages from 3rd NuGet package source. In Visual Studio, I can use `Options - NuGet Package Manager - Package sources` to set another package source, in command-line, how to do it?

Error log can be seen in [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/DSRYhh/BuptAssistant/builds/215869660)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a `Nuget.Config` file in the same directory as your solution (`.sln`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v3/" />
    <add key="MyCustomSource" value="https://yournnugetserver.com/api/v3/" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Or:

```
nuget sources Add -Name "MyCustomSource" -source https://yournnugetserver.com/api/v3/
nuget restore MySolution.sln
```

Or:

```
nuget restore MySolution.sln -source "https://www.nuget.org/api/v3;https://yournnugetserver.com/api/v3/"
```